# How to migrate from Prisma 1 to Prisma 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, prisma

Trying to to migrate from Prisma 1 to Prisma 2 and all seems to work, i.e. I can query my database fine. Except when running `npx prisma migrate dev` which seems to think my schema is out of date and says `We need to reset the PostgreSQL database`

Is there a way I can tell Prisma that the schema in my database is the one I want to keep?

The flow I have done to migrate is as follows:

1. Using `pg_dump` to pull down prisma 1 database
2. Use `pg_restore` to upload copy of prisma 1 database to a new database
3. Using `npx prisma-upgrade` to generate SQL commands to run on new database
4. Running `prisma introspect` which shows successful (a few warnings `These id fields were enriched with` @default(cuid()) `information taken from the previous Prisma schema.` but shouldn't be a blocker?)
5. Run `npx prisma generate` and can succesfully generate my client which I can use to query data and all seems to work fine
6. Run `prisma migrate dev` which is what doesn't work `Drift detected: Your database schema is not in sync with your migration history` & `We need to reset the PostgreSQL database`

I don't want to reset my database as I'll lose all my data.

Is it possible to delete these migrations from somewhere so it thinks my database schema is up to date or will that cause issues downt the track?

Perhaps there is a better way to handle this upgrade / migration?

Comment: The [migration guide](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/upgrade-guides/upgrade-from-prisma-1/how-to-upgrade) can probably help you with your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Reyno, have been using that as a guide but doesn't seem to have anything about the `prisma migration dev` trying to reset the database.

Comment: It has a page about Migration troubleshooting in development. May be you have a problem with your migration history. pls see at [link](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/troubleshooting-development#handling-migration-history-conflicts)